# Structure of "what...waste my waking..."

Tags: word-usage, grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Excerpted from *Araby* by *James Joyce*:

> What innumerable follies laid waste my waking and sleeping thoughts after the evening!

I can't understand the sentence structure above, *What* at the beginning indicates it's exclamatory, but I don't see the normal structure of exclamatory sentence. *Lay* is supposed to have some nouns after it, so I assume *waste* is a noun there, but then how can *my waking* attached directly after a noun like that?

Comment: Assuming you can parse exclamatory *What an interesting question this is!*, the only other aspect of the text that might be troublesome is the poetic/dated/literary phrasal noun ***to lay waste (to something)***, which means [*to cause extensive destruction or ruin utterly.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lay+waste+to). Note that (syntactically optional) *waking and sleeping* applies adjectivally to *thoughts*, as does the final (also syntactically optional) adverbial phrase *after the evening*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What X" is indeed exclamatory - slightly outdated in this usage I'd say, but not too uncommon in classic literature.

"To lay waste to something" is a compound expression, roughly meaning "to destroy" ("Godzilla laid waste to the entire city", for example). I'm not sure why it's used without 'to' after 'waste' here, but usually that's included in common usage.

And "waking" shouldn't be taken on its own in this sentence; it acts as a descriptor for "thoughts" -- "waking and sleeping thoughts" implying "thoughts throughout the entire day and night".

Answer (score 1):

I would consider *lay waste* to be a phrasal verb.  Someone may argue the technicality of that, but for practical purposes it's easiest if you consider both of those words as the verb like other phrasal verbs.

(I would say it's more usual to say *lay waste to*, e.g. "The army efficiently laid waste to the enemy's arsenal." but it's not strictly needed.)

*Thoughts* is the object of *lay waste*.

*My waking and sleeping* are modifiers (adjectives) to *thoughts*.  Adjectives usually go in front of nouns in English, so this is normal.

> I threw darts at Suzy's picture.
>
> I threw the green ball at Suzy.
>
> I threw my old almost completely torn apart ball at Suzy.